# I wrote codes to upload image in PHP. But I got the error as below. Now what should I do to solve this?

Tags: php, image, xampp, image-uploading

I have a PHP-project, but I'm getting the errors below. How can I fix these?

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(photos/pic1.jpg): failed to open stream:
> Permission denied in
> /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/uploads/upload.php on line 16
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move
> '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/php7RZaLG' to 'photos/pic1.jpg'
> in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/uploads/upload.php on line 16

```
<?php 

$image_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$image_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
$image_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
$image_tmp_name = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {
    # code...
    if ($image_name == '') {
        # code...
        echo "Please choose an Image";
        exit();
    }
    else{
        move_uploaded_file($image_tmp_name, "photos/$image_name");
        echo "Image Uploaded Successfully!!!";
    }
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Photo Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="image">
        <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload Now">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Fix the permissions.

Comment: You have no permissions to move the file, as the first warning says. Please append your PHP code and try to change the folder permissions.

Comment: How can I change the folder permissions?

Comment: Are you running on Windows or *nix

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your `/photos/` directory 'writable'.

There are a number of ways to do this.

- Use an FTP client to manually alter the file permissions on the directory to make it writable
- Use PHP (if you have 'permission' to alter 'permissions' via PHP) to alter the permissions

http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php

You will need to pass the FULL SERVER PATH to your 'photos' directory to the `chmod()` function, followed by the permission level that you require.
eg:

```
chmod('/full/path/to/photos',0755);
```

Comment: Can copy this line in my main php file?

Comment: Alter the '/full/path' to the correct value and try it.  If it throws an error that you do not have permission to run this - you will know that you do not have permission to do this.

Comment: Should I copy this line in my php file?

Comment: Ooops, meant `chmod()`..  Answer modified.

Comment: @Yash Yes, place the line at the top of the page.

Comment: Should I have to write full URL in this function?

Comment: Yes, you need to pass the FULL SERVER PATH to the directory that you want to change permissions on

Comment: Actually I am a beginner. So, sorry to bother you but could you please write that URL for me?